convex hull of points uniformly drawn from a ball in $\mathbb R^d$.
It is known that the expected number of vertexes of the convex hull generated by $N$ points randomly drawn from a ball in $\mathbb R^d$ with uniform distribution grows as $N^{d-1/d+1}$. I'm interested in the case d bigger than or equal to $4$. Is there any result on the variance of the number of vertexes?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Can you provide background to make this question useful to others?  Do you have a reference for that fact about the expected number of vertices?  What precisely do you mean by "grows as" -- is that an asymptotic statement, with lower-order terms ignored, or what?  What kind of result are you looking for?

Let me add some additional information:

Let me add some additional information:


"grows as" is an asumptotic statement; it means that the quantity of interest is $C N^{d-1/d+1}(1 + o(1))$, with $C$ a constant;


the result can e.g. be read in Section 5 of "RANDOM POINTS AND LATTICE POINTS
IN CONVEX BODIES", I. BARANY, BULLETIN OF THE AM. MATH. SOC., Volume 45, 2008, Pages 339–365.


I'm interested to know whether the number of vertexes somehow concentrates about its mean (e.g., variance not too large) because this implies a small volume of the convex hull, hence a high risk to have a next point outside the convex hull.



I guess you mean $N^{(d-1)/(d+1)}$, right?

right, sorry, it was initially written as $N^\frac{d-1}{d+1}$.

cannot find how the variance goes. There are results when $d=2$, but can't find extesion for d = 4 or above with uniform distribution on the ball.
